# Portable generator with starter solenoid problem

Tags: starting

My portable is similar to King Canada KCG-6500GE. When the battery is connected, the starter is automatically engaged even if starting switch is in run position. I checked voltage on the 2 big posts of the solenoid and read 12.6V (battery's output).
Should I assumed that the starter solenoid is frozen in hot position or should I be looking at the 6 wires / 3 positions switch (offf-run-start)? If so, how to test this switch.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Disconnect the small solenoid wire from starter, then connect DC voltmeter, does it have battery voltage? If so it is the switch, if not it is the solenoid.

Comment: I did disconnect that wire and yes there was battery voltage on both poles.

Comment: I would replace the switch.

Answer (score 0):

This might be something as simple as a short in the start button on the thin wire to the solenoid.

Disconnect the wire on the solenoid,does this disengage the start solenoid if yes the fault is on the thin wire and if not the contacts on the start relay is burned and you need to replace it.